# Recycler view is not update when using carrousel manager library

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to pull image data into Recycler view (each sub item is a PagerSnapHelper element) but faced below problem
1 - recycler view is not getting update when first time load, sub elements seems to be misalignment. 
2 - i have to slide or touch the screen to reload the view, all elements is showing ok then.

**the faulty one, when the first time load Recycler view**
[image: the faulty one, when the first time load Recycler view]

**the correct one, after i swipe the view**
[image: the correct one, after i swipe the view]

In Activity

```
override fun onGetDataSuccess(obj: RESP_DetailDiscover.ObjectDetailDiscover) {
        if (obj.gallery_popup.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            adapterPopup.setListData(mutableListOf())
        } else {
            adapterPopup.setListData(obj.gallery_popup)
        }
}

adapterPopup = PopupAdapter(applicationContext)
        val layoutManager = ZoomCenterCardLayoutManager(this)
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL)
        val snapHelper = PagerSnapHelper()
        snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rcvPopup)

        rcvPopup.addOnScrollListener(CenterScrollListener())
        rcvPopup.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                rcvPopup.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                val range = this@DetailDiscoverActivity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.width_item_horizontal_popup).toInt()
                val margin = this@DetailDiscoverActivity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.margin_item_horizontal_popup).toInt()
                val extent = (rcvPopup.getWidth() - range) / 2 - margin
                rcvPopup.setPadding(extent, 0, extent, 0)
                rcvPopup.setClipToPadding(false)
            }
        })
        rcvPopup.layoutManager = layoutManager
        rcvPopup.adapter = adapterPopup
        layoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition(rcvPopup, null, 0)
        rcvPopup.addItemDecoration(LinePagerIndicatorDecoration())
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you set list data you have to `notifyDataSetChange()` on your adapter . In that way you will tell your program that : "Hey , I have updated something , show it to me !"

```
fun setListData(list: ArrayList<GalleryPopupObjectOrSomethingLikeThat>) {
  yourAdapterList = list
  notifyDataSetChange()
}
```